# How to understand the cursor description returned columns in HDB from python

Tags: python, sql, hana

I am trying to understand what each field in the tuple returned from curs.description so I can know what the type is and parameters of that type.

See the code samples below. I basically will run some query and then print or manipulate the cursor description (which is a tuple). What does the data mean (I know one of the fields is the column name)? I want to understand what all these fields mean so I can parse any type information as needed.

for example, here is an SAP HANA query

```sql
select *
from "_NAMESPACE"."SomeTable"
```

which I run from python

```py
conn01 = pyhdb.connect(host='', port=, user='', password = '')
curs02 = conn01.cursor()
curs02.execute(myQuery)
curs02.fetchone()
print(curs02.description) # prints tuple
```

Returns (for example):

(('FROM_SITE', 11, None, 1, 0, None, 2),
 ('TO_SITE', 11, None, 1, 0, None, 2),
 ('FROM', 11, None, 4, 0, None, 0),
 ('TO', 11, None, 4, 0, None, 0),
 ('TRX', 11, None, 2, 0, None, 0),
 ('ACCNUM', 11, None, 8, 0, None, 0),
 ('DESC', 11, None, 20, 0, None, 2),
 ('DMYNUM', 3, None, 10, 0, None, 0))

I would like to understand what all the fields within each tuple element is. For example, ('FROM_SITE', 11, None, 1, 0, None, 2). E.g., what is each field signify. "11" seems to signify varchar, but I don't understand all of these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values are:

```
name
type_code
display_size
internal_size
precision
scale
null_ok
```

Per the [DB-API documentation.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)

Note that, depending on the DBMS in use, the `type_code` that is returned may not conform to the DB-API specification.

Comment: Thank you!! Is there a reference for what number for the type_code corresponds to what human readable type? From the link you shared, I see the names but not a cross-reference to a number. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#type-objects

Comment: No.  At one time I compiled a cross-reference table of the `type_code`s used by various DBMSs for different data types, and there is no consistency.  Your best bet is to create a table with columns containing all data types (that you care about), query it, and inspect the `type_code` values that you get back.

Answer (score 2):

The type_code numbers returned by `pyhdb` are HANA specific. The number directly corresponds with the type code field returned by the HANA server in the network protocol. This number can change, depending on the client and server version, even if the corresponding column type appears the same.

A list of the known type_code numbers can be found in the `pyhdb` source code:

https://github.com/SAP/PyHDB/blob/master/pyhdb/protocol/constants/type_codes.py

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! That's what I've been working for.